# Getting class Not Found Issue

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, tomcat8

```
Aug 22, 2023 9:01:02 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class [com.linkdom.intercom.listener.ContextListener]
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.linkdom.intercom.listener.ContextListener
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1420)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1228)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:487)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:469)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4404)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4935)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1360)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1350)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)

Aug 22, 2023 9:01:02 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Skipped installing application listeners due to previous error(s)
Aug 22, 2023 9:01:02 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInte
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You may already have guessed that ClassNotFoundException meens that a class can not be found (by the classloader). In this case is the class `com.linkdom.intercom.listener.ContextListener` not available to the classloader.

You may check that you have the library, that includes this file, on the classpath, ie in your war-file that is deployed in Tomcat or in the `/lib` folder in Tomcat (there can be other options where the library may be added to the classpath depending on your setup).

Comment: actually this a custome file included in my dir

Comment: Make sure your custom java file is compiled and that the resulting class-file (not the java-file) is included  on the classpath